# An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_I4) error

Tags: ssis

I have a simple sql statement which outputs a few columns, whch one of them is a column with an int datatype, but I get the following error when I execute the package, I tried to change the datatype in the flat file but it doesn't seem to work:

[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query SELECT schema_name(tab.schema_id) AS schema_name, ... failed with the following error: An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_I4). Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, ResultSet property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Would you please let me know what could be done to fix the issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please run this query (SELECT schema_name(tab.schema_id) AS schema_name) using Management studio? Your query seems to be incorrect, just as the message showed (Problems with the query)

Comment: You can also go to the advanced editor in the data flow task to see what data types it has listed in there.  If you made changes they may not have been updated.  Or you have invalid data.  You said you updated the data in the flat file, are you sure the columns are matching and all values are INT?

Comment: @OzanSen thank you for your reply, the script executes successfully and has the correct output in SSMS, but there seems to be an issue running it in Visual studio

Comment: @Brad thank you for your reply, all the columns have the correct and matched  datatypes - and are all matching from the source to the destination

Comment: @sql100 Good to hear it! Now is the vital 2nd step. Please change the data type of variable (DBTYPE_I4) to string! Because your query result returns a string and you try to insert it into a variable whose data type is INT, resulting in failure! Then run the ETL code again in VS.